# efficient way to extract list elements containing at least a term of another list

Tags: python, performance, list

I have 2 lists.
One is a list of strings. Call it A.
The other is a list of terms. Call it B.

I need to extract from the list of string those elements which contain at least a term included in the list of terms.

A nested for loop is obviously a possibility:

```
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if b in a:
            print (a)
```

This is O(n^2), this is not a good approach since A is very long (1 billion strings!).

The other solution I thought is:
split a and sort it by length and then use the inverted lists method.

I have not timed it yet but it should be slightly better.

Any hint on alternative approaches is really welcome!

Comment: Can you explain by any example test case?

Comment: Agreed, it's not clear what shape your data has.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sets:

```
from itertools import chain

set_a = set(a)
terms = set(chain.from_iterable(b))
has_terms = set_a & terms
```

Comment: Cool. As easy as genial. I will time it. Thank you!

Comment: @user3623123 I'm not sure its correct. Can you add an example of input and output?

Comment: @user3623123: yes, please provide sample A, B and expected result, so we can verify.